# Using SSE with Laravel without querying the database

Tags: php, laravel, server-sent-events

I am developing a real-time dashboard where I want to notify the clients when there are new data so they refresh the dashboard. Since the clients don't send any data to the server, I thought using Server sent events would be better than using web sockets.

Here's the backend code:

```
   $response->setCallback(
            function() {
                while(true) {
                    echo "retry: 100\n\n";
                    if($this->needRefresh() == 1) {
                        echo "data: 1\n\n";
                        $this->setRefreshFalse();
                    }
                    ob_flush();
                    flush();
                    sleep(3);
                }
            });
```

I have created a table with a single row, where it's value is set to true whenever there's new data.
The `$this->needRefresh()` function hits the database every 3 seconds.
So if there're many clients this will be a load on the server.
I want to ask if there's any other way to trigger the SSE without having to hit the database every 3 seconds.

Comment: May be you can use redis. Since its ram memory based so no disk io overhead.

Comment: If this dashboard is the same for all users and all users need to refresh it at the same time then I would argue that using websockets is much better than SSE in this case.

Comment: @Oshanz I used redis and it worked fine thanks.

Comment: @MohamedLOTFY I add the answer, now you can give me a few points :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, you can use Redis. a key values data structure is good enough to cater this requirement. since you need to avoid Disk IO consider Redis or Memcache. Redis is a high-performance in-memory data store with configurable persistence.